# Can I launch the process when it was generating core dump?

Tags: linux

I have a monitor script will check a specified process, if it crash, the script will relaunch it without waiting for the core dump writing complete. Does this incur bad things? Will it affect the core dump file or the relaunched process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can launch processes any time you like, whether or not other processes are running the same executable, irrespective of their being dumping core.  However, two simultaneous core dumps may overwrite each other unless you provide for them to have different file names.  That can be achieved by setting `kernel.core_pattern` appropriately; for example, having the process id (`%p`) be part of it.  See *Naming of core dump files* in [core(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) man page.